# Does a global PHP variable always contain its most recent value at runtime?

Tags: php

Scenario:

1. there is a global array `$cache`.
2. there is 1 function, `cacheWriter()`, that updates `$cache` with
   various cachable objects. `cacheWriter()` runs a switch() with
   different cases that each update a certain key in `$cache`.
3. some cases in `cacheWriter()` depend on other cases to correctly
   update `$cache`. In these cases, the script checks if the array key
   it depends on already exists in `$cache`, and if not, it will call
   `cacheWriter()` from within to get the case it needs.

In these cases, will `$cache` already be updated and contain the new content, or only the next time the function runs?

Example:

```
function cacheWriter($case) {
    global $cache;

    if($cache[$case]) {
        $out = $cache[$case];

    } else {

        switch($case) {
            case 1 : 
                $cache[1] = 'some object';
            break;

            case 2 :
                if(!$cache[1]) {
                    $dummy = cacheWriter(1);
                }

                //QUESTION:
                //will $cache[1] now exist right here (since it's global)
                //so that I can now simply access it like this:

                $cache[2] = $cache[1]->xyz;

                //OR,
                //do I have to use $dummy to get [1]
                //and $cache[1] will only exist the next time the function runs?            

            break;
        }

        $out = $cache[$case];
    }

    return $out;

}//cacheWriter()
```

Obviously, this function is extremely simplified, but it's the basic concept. Thanks!

Comment: PHP is not multithreaded, so if you update a global, that new value is immediately in effect everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's what I needed to know. Do you want to add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: See [globals in php mean something different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the value of the global will contain the last write. The `global` directive is for *scoping* purposes, to tell the interpreter which variable to use - it doesn't actually "import" the value and hold onto it at that point.